# Show div on top of another div using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I have a product page which is populated my Locayta.  It populates with div's containing an image.  Let's call this div "a".  There are x-amount of products and thus x-amount of div "a"'s, all with the same id.

Using jQuery, I would like a div "b" to appear on top of whichever div "a" is hovered over, and then for div "b" to leave when the hover stops.

To clarify, since there are many div "a"'s, I need to target "this" div a, the one which has the mouse hovering over it, and either move an existing div "b" on top of this "a" or create a div "b" on top of this "a".

So far I have tried .after, .insertAfter and .prop but unsure which is most suited to this situation

One method I have considered but would nee help with the code, is to have both divs like this:

```
<div id="a"><img src="img.jpg"></div>

<div id="b" style="display:none;"><img src="img2.jpg"></div>

Then when the user hovers over div "a", div "b" should sit on top of div "a" and display:none should be removed.  Thoughts?
```

I had this question open previously with my real code included but it just confused things.

Any advice is greatly appreciated!

EDIT:

RESOLVED USING THE FOLLOWING SOLUTION:

```
jQuery('#main_cat_prods').delegate('img', 'mouseenter', function(){
            var $skuID = this.src.match(/[a-z][a-z][a-z]\d\d\d\d\d/)[0];

        if ( !jQuery('#QuickBuyProdBox').length ) {
            jQuery(this).closest('.image').prepend('<div id="QuickBuyProdBox" style="width:50px; height:50px; position:absolute; background-color:red; cursor:pointer;">');
        };
            jQuery("#QuickBuyProdBox").click(function(){
                jQuery.event.trigger('lightbox', $skuID);
            });
            jQuery('.image, #QuickBuyProdBox').mouseleave(function(){
            jQuery('#QuickBuyProdBox').remove();
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `a` and `b` are classes, rather than and ID (as IDs should be unique on a page):

```
$('.a').hover(function() {
    var buttonCopy = $('.b').clone();
    $(this).find('img').after(buttonCopy);
    buttonCopy.show();
},
function() {
    $(this).find('.b').remove();
});
```

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7uHAJ/)

You should be able to alter this into a working form if you *absolutely* must use IDs (e.g. put he hover on `#parentContainer > div`), but it'll be very hacky and I'd recommend against it. [Here's an example of how to handle it.](http://jsfiddle.net/7uHAJ/1/)

```
$('#wrapper > div').hover(function() {
    var buttonCopy = $('#b').clone();
    $(this).find('img').after(buttonCopy);
    buttonCopy.show();
},
function() {
    $(this).find('#b').remove();
});
```

If your CMS is spitting out identical IDs onto the page, I'd suggest changing the template.

Comment: Great answer - thank you.  Any chance you could modify your fiddle using ID's?  Much appreciated man! :)

Comment: Updated with ID version - but multiple identical IDs may cause issues in some browsers so your real-world mileage may vary.

Answer (score 2):

Demo : **[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hardik1988/amJw5/4/)**

Try below code sample :

**CSS :**

```
<style type="text/css">
    .container {
        background-color: #bababa;
        width: 200px;
        height: 30px;
    }

    .tooltip {
        position: absolute;
        background-color: #333;
        border: 1px solid orange;
        width: 50px;
        height: 30px;
    }
</style>
```

**HTML :**

```
<div id="a" class="container">
    <img src="img.jpg">
</div><br/><br/>
<div id="a" class="container">
    <img src="img.jpg">
</div><br/><br/>
<div id="a" class="container">
    <img src="img.jpg">
</div><br/><br/>
<div id="a" class="container">
    <img src="img.jpg">
</div>
<div id="b" style="display: none;" class="tooltip">
    <img src="img2.jpg">
</div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT :**

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $('.container').hover(function (evt) {
        $("#b").show();
        $("#b").css({
            top: evt.pageY,
            left: evt.pageX
        });
    });

    $('.container').mouseout(function()
    {
        $("#b").hide();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Great answer Spider!  One problem with this though, is that the div "b" is appearing all over the place and flashing!  Is there any way to prevent this with something like settimeout, and making its position absolute inside "a"?  So that it only appears in the same place on "a"?  Thanks again! :)

Comment: Are you asking about flickering ? which is happening two or three times show-hide-show-hide-show like that ?

Comment: resolved the issue of flashing. check the updated code and demo as well. thanks

Answer (score 2):

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JfEPA/

```
$('.product').hover(function(){

    $('#target').css({top:$(this).offset().top, left: $(this).offset().left});
})
```

You have specified that you are using `id`s for the divs. You should not use the same ids and instead use same classes for the same.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
$('.a-class').on('mouseenter', function() {
 $('.b-class').show();
});
```

Answer (score -1):

If you put div b inside a then you can css your way out of some of it with:

.a-class:hover .b-class { display: block }

Comment: I don't have access to the HTML, it's generated externally.  Hence I need to use jQuery.  Also, as I stipulated in the question there are multiple divs with the same id, using CSS would apply this rule to ALL of them.